# Jenkins with linux machine for selenium script

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins

I have created selenium testng.xml file and make windows batch file for my local window machine and Jenkins build now function perfectly working

But now client expectation is run jenkins projects for same selenium script in Linux server machine.

I m not aware about how can i start for my testng file for linux server?

Comment: have you configured jenkins in your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You created batch file while working with testng.xml on Windows. You would create an equivalent shell file while working with testng.xml on Linux.

Once done, Go to Jenkins Job configuration build section and select **Execute Shell** option.

Put you shell script in command window or execute shell file directly from command window itself.

To execute shell file, use below syntax:

```
./<file>
```

Comment: I have window batch files code like as  "java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG login.xml" but how can I creat Linux shell script. I totally unaware about it

Comment: You created batch file that will only work on your windows machine. Linux is completely different system and doesn't support extensions like .bat, .exe and many others which are supported in Windows. Share you .bat file and I will look if I can modify it to work on Linux.

Comment: java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG Property_Addj.xml

Comment: java -cp "lib/*:bin:" org.testng.TestNG Property_Addj.xml

Comment: save it with extension .sh and run ./<file-name>

Comment: Still getting stuck in console output:                                                                      Started by user admin
Building in workspace /home/administrator/AutomationSICASA

[AutomationSICASA] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1131940601674598183.sh
+ ./login1.sh
/tmp/jenkins1131940601674598183.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins1131940601674598183.sh: ./login1.sh: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Xvfb stopping
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Oh! Please give permissions to file. Try sudo chmod 777 <filename> Well It's not always recommended to use 777 or to change default permissions in Linux for security purposes.

Comment: Can u help how can I do?

Comment: Mark answer as accepted if that worked for you so that it can help others too.